# How to update a laravel project on AWS

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm new to AWS. I uploaded a laravel project to AWS using elastic beanstalk and users uploaded videos and I'm saving the videos inside the public folder. Now I did few updates and I want to upload a newer version of the laravel project. If I uploaded a new version. Does that replace the public folder on AWS with with one in the uploaded version? I don't want to lose the videos that the users uploaded. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does that replace the public folder on AWS with with one in the uploaded version? I don't want to lose the videos that the users uploaded.

**Yes it does**, and you will probably loose data after update. If not, then you will loos data due to **auto-scaling events** (automated termination by AWS and creation of a replacement) on your EB instance.

Therefore, its not a good practice to keep your videos on the instance itself. Instead, they should be stored **outside the instance**. Usually, for this purpose, **S3 or EFS services** are used. This way, you store data outside of your EB environment, and you will not loose it due to updates or auto-scaling events.

Comment: @AhmedAbdeen No problem. Glad I could help.